# Tool to collect and learn new words and idioms

Tags: language

I am looking for a tool for collecting, learning, usage analyzing of idioms or just new words. I see that it can be application with web- and mobile interfaces for input new words with well-known definition or provided by me. The application should provide some "learning mode". And most useful is functionality to analyze usage of idioms in documents, conversations etc (like Grammarly).

I read question Is “memrise” approach good for memorizing English words?: Is "memrise" approach good for memorizing English words? It is partly about tools, I tried memorize but it is about it's own lessons, not idioms collecting tool like I want.

What tool suits me better?

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! What OS must that tool run on? What is your price limit? What features do you need?

Answer (score 2):

Check out My Word List.

It is an Android word list app with an offline dictionary that contains over 800,000 words, terms and idioms.
You can also create your own personal list, add your own idioms, and enter your own notes.

Links:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fortylove.mywordlist.free

Disclaimer: Answer provided by developer of app in question.

Answer (score 1):

I use Anki. It has a simple web interface and an android app.

The questions+answers are avilable offline on the mobile phone. That's a feature I really like.

Answer (score 0):

Most similar tool. that I found by recommendation is Quizlet:
https://quizlet.com

It allows to collect modules with words/phrases and learn it in different ways after it.
I just started using it, so do not know how useful it will be in practice.

Comment: Time has passed. Do you still use it? If not, which tool do you use now?

Answer (score 0):

There is a web site thats been around a long time called 'A word a day'. You get sent (used to be by email) with a new unusual word everyday. The message included a wav file for pronunciation and I think site took feedback. If this is what you were looking for. If not, sorry..